# Declare array of Object, within the Object's constructor?

Tags: c++

If I have a class, MyClass, can I declare an array of MyClass on the heap, within the constructor of MyClass?

I can do this in C# but it doesnt seem to like it in C++?

I also get an error about no appropriate constructor for type MyClass??

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass(int);
    private
        MyClass* array;
};


MyClass::MyClass(int size){
    array = new MyClass[size];
}
```

Comment: You'd run out of memory, yes? Because the constructors chain together, just eating up more and more of (heap or stack, doesn't matter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to have an array of something, said something has to be *default-constructible*. Your `MyClass` isn't since it needs an `int` to be constructed.

What C# does is comparable to:

```
MyClass** array = new MyClass*[size];
```

Where pointers are default constructible, so its allowed. Basically, whenever you do `SomeObject` in C# its the equivalent of `SomeObject*` in C++. Except that the code would be horribly inefficient, even worse than its C# counterpart, and there would be leaks everywhere.

Comment: Is that line of code what I could use to fix it? Would there be any special way which I have to use the array afterwards?

Comment: @Jon: No, that's not how you fix it, that's how you work around it. Is there a reason for `MyClass` not to be _default-constructible_?

Comment: I just want to store an collection of MyClass objects where I can traverse through. In C# I wouldnt use Lists, I would just create an array of MyClass[]

Comment: This also means the constructor of the class isn't called within itself, which would lead to problems.

Comment: @tmpearce: I failed to notice that! You should place a proper answer, I'd +1 it.

Comment: Im guessing I should just use a vector?

Comment: @Jon: That'd depend, do you want objects (values) or references (pointers)?

Comment: wouldnt i have to have objects/values elsewhere if i used references/pointers? i just want to store a collection of type MyClass objects

Comment: @Jon: That'd mean that each of your classes would have an array with a number of other objects of the same type, which themselves would contain an array with a number of other of the same type, which themselves would contain an array with a number of other of the same type, which themselves would contain an array with a number of other of the same type, which themselves would contain an array with a number of other of the same type, which themselves would contain an array with a number of other of the same type, which themselves would contain an array with a number of other of the same type...

Comment: @K-ballo, I am writing my own recursive tree-like structure

Comment: @Jon: Then you need dynamic allocation, and hence pointers. Using a standard container like `std::vector` would indeed be a better solution.

Comment: @K-ballo (and Jon) Populating a std::vector *within the constructor* will lead to exactly the same problem with chaining constructors.  Rethink the design!

Comment: @tmpearce: Not necessarily, since the number of items it creates is a parameter to the constructor... but I guess the OP would fall in the trap you mention.

Comment: @K-ballo Yes, true: it is *very important* that within the constructor, objects of `A` only be pushed onto the vector with the constructor taking `0` as an argument.  Note that I'm not objecting to your answer per se, but rather pointing out that there is still a serious pitfall waiting to happen even while using std::vector.

Comment: @tmpearce: Don't worry, I don't like this design either... In fact I'd +1 your answer. However, this is the kind of thing that happens when someone tries to write C# code in C++, instead of taking the time to learn the language.

Answer (score 3):

You have a more fundamental problem with your approach here than how to construct an array.

Think about it this way:

```
class A
{
   A* a;
public:
   A();
};
A::A()
{
   a = new A();
}
```

What happens? You try and create an `A`; within the constructor, a `new A` is created.  Within *that* constructor, another `new A` is created...

Boom, out of memory.